# Git add different alias/nickname for remote regarding fetch and push

Tags: git

I want to have the following:

`git remote -v`

`from_gitlab  git@gitlab.com:<username>/<remote_repo_name> (fetch)
to_gitlab   git@gitlab.com:<username>/<remote_repo_name> (push)`

So I can have self documenting commands such as:

`git push to_gitlab master`

and

`git pull from_gitlab master`

How would I do this?

I know about `git remote add` but it adds for both `fetch` and `push`.

I'd like a command such as (note this is fictional): `git remote add --fetch` and `git remote add --push` to add a nickname/alias for both push and fetch respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hackish way of doing it. Any less hackish way would be appreciated. Here are the commands:

For push:

`git remote add to_gitlab no_pulling`

`git remote set-url --push to_gitlab git@gitlab.com:mettamage_proton/fruit-calculator.git`

For pull:

`git remote add from_gitlab git@gitlab.com:<username>/<online_repo_name>`

`git remote set-url --push no_pushing`

Result with `git remote -v`:

`to_gitlab    no_pulling (fetch)
to_gitlab   git@gitlab.com:<username>/<online_repo_name> (push)
from_gitlab git@gitlab.com:<username>/<online_repo_name> (fetch)
from_gitlab no_pushing (push)`